# How to fake the HTTP_USER_AGENT in a Symfony2 Listener UnitTest?

Tags: php, phpunit, symfony-2.8

I have a Listener, which behaves differently depending on the HTTP_USER_AGENT:

```
        if ($request->server->get('HTTP_USER_AGENT') == $this->zabbixUserAgent) {
            VisitorHolder::set($visitor);
        } else {
            VisitorHolder::set($this->visitorService->persist($visitor));
        }
```

I want to avoid saving all Zabbix requests to our database. That works fine, but how can I fake the user agent in my unit test, so that my tests cover this case?

Creating a new Request and setting the user agent there is thoroughly ignored:

```
    $this->currentRequest = new Request(
        [], // GET parameters
        [], // POST parameters
        [], // request attributes (parameters parsed from the PATH_INFO, ...)
        [], // COOKIE parameters
        [], // FILES parameters
        ['HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'zbx'], // SERVER parameters
        null // raw body data
    );

    $this->requestStack
        ->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getCurrentRequest')
        ->willReturn($this->currentRequest);
```

A var_dump in the unit test tells me, that my user agent is still null and my case is not covered.
Any idea how I can set the user agent for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you extracted the actual check to a function elsewhere in the class, you can then mock or otherwise override that check within the class and keep it as a unit-test that does not need to fake a HTTP request at all.

For full integration tests, If you extracted the actual check to a separate service, then you can override the check with a difference configuration in a config_test.yml file, and using a different copy of the service that will always report false in a test-environment.

```
# config_test.yml file:
app_zabbix_detect.detector:
    class: AppBundle\Services\ZabbixDetectorAlwaysFalse
```

In the main file it would be

```
# config.yml file: (or services.yml)
app_zabbix_detect.detector:
    class: AppBundle\Services\ZabbixDetector # real test
```

Comment: Ah ok you propose I write a kind of userAgentCheckerHelper which I can then mock if needed?

Comment: A function in the class, or a service to wrap the function, yes.

Comment: How about mocking $request->server->get ? 
I considered that, but since there is nothing like a getServer method to mock I got stuck there.
Do you have any idea to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Symfony v6.4

In Test:

```php
$client = static::createClient(array(), array(
        'HTTP_HOST' => 'mySymfonyApp', // Set HOST HTTP Header.
        'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'Symfony Browser/1.0', // Set Agent header.
));
```

Get the browser(user agent) detail in Controller:

```php
$param->setCreatedUserAgent($request->server->get('HTTP_USER_AGENT'));
```

If this is in production environment, you get the browser(user agent) details.